# Where can I find best practice info on SCM (perforce)

Tags: version-control, perforce

BLUF: I am looking for SCM best practices for large / complex java based project.

DETAILS:

In my environment we have a single production DB cluster that is being accessed concurrently by a variety of different web applications.

Our code is structured so that common functionality is extracted into separate projects and the resultant jars are then shared by the web applications.

I am looking for SCM best practices that would apply to this scale of development.

Through the reading I have done I have seen a number of SCM patterns like 'Main Line' mentioned.  Is there a central repository of SCM patterns?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Practical Perforce](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101856) includes a great deal of general SCM advice, but also gives the specific Perforce commands required to perform the actions recommended.

Note that this book was written by a Perforce employee...

Comment: It is perforce orientated but I think it's also an excellent book on SCM in general

Comment: I own this book and agree with your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the online article [High-level Best Practices
in Software Configuration Management](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/papers/bestpractices.html).

Answer (score 0):

Some books on SCM patterns and principles:

- [Software Configuration Management Patterns: Effective Teamwork, Practical Integration](http://www.scmpatterns.com/book/) by Steve Berczuk
- [Configuration Management Principles and Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321117662) by Anne Mette Jonassen Hass
- [Anti-Patterns and Patterns in Software Configuration Management](http://www.amazon.com/Anti-Patterns-Patterns-Software-Configuration-Management/dp/047132929) - William Brown, et al.